# Changing name of viewstate

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have two ASP.NET form living in the same page.  I some problems because the hidden fields below get the same name and id.

Is there some way I can change these for one of the forms?
(They are also not optimal for validation).

I need the services the viewstate provides, but perhaps I could disable it on form level, and use it at a lower (control) level?

Answer (score 3):

It's not what you want to hear, but in ASP.Net you should only have one `runat="server"` form per page.  Otherwise this is just the first of many other problems you will encounter.

Comment: What kind of problems?  This is also about HTML validation:
"value of attribute "ID" invalid: "_" cannot start a name."
(its not really 2 runat="server" - these are forms from 2 GETs inserted in a classic .asp file)